# Java video chat in client/server

Tags: java, video, chat, jmf

I need to know that how to implement a video chat program in my java project.
i am hear about jmf but am not so happy with that library, any library is there to work with this (eg: skype api).

Answer (score 1):

Use [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) with [java interface](https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/). refer these tutorials to find [how to use GStreamer](https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/Tutorials)

Comment: Hi Can you tell any live demo link  using GStream?